# Global FIlter no MVC 5 não está funcionando

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

Olá.
Estou o seguindo o tutorial abaixo com o intenção de entender melhor o processo de autenticação do .net Identity com OWIN.

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1

Quando acesso a Home, ele deveria redirecionar para o auth/login e não está acontecendo isso. É como se estivesse ignorando o AuthorizeAttribute().

Seguem meus códigos.

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(DotNetIdentidade.Startup))]

namespace DotNetIdentidade
    {
        public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/auth/login")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**FilterConfig.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace DotNetIdentidade
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace DotNetIdentidade
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);  
        }
    }
}
```

Grato.

Comment: Cadê o código do `HomeController`?

Comment: E ai Cigano. Estou sem o pc agora. Mas o código da HomeController é básico, não fiz nenhuma alteração quando criei. Pelo que percebi no tutorial, a ideia é não autorizar o acesso de nenhum controller a menos aqueles que eu coloco como [AllowAnonymous].

Comment: Verdade. O tutorial sugere isso. Preciso testar também porque uso outra abordagem: marco com `[Authorize]` onde quero autenticação.

Comment: Hoje de manhã liguei meu PC, não mudei nada no projeto e agora quando fui rodar funcionou como descrito no tutorial. Será que está relacionado com a reinicialização do PC? Algum cache em que o GlobalFilter não era atualizado? Antes de postar minha dúvida eu já havia dado um Clean na solution, um rebuild e nada.

Comment: Pensando um pouco melhor, se eu alterei o Global.asax eu tenho que reiniciar a aplicação para que o IIS visualize minhas alterações. Faz sentido? Se sim, então certamente esta foi a causa. Eu já havia rodado a aplicação uma vez e o IIS Express utilizou a mesma instância já iniciada com o Global.asax antigo.

Comment: Pode ser várias coisas. Pena eu não poder responder pra você com algo útil :/ O Global.asax é uma delas.

Answer (score 2):

Após reiniciar o pc o código funcionou como esperado.
Acredito que tenha alguma relação com a reinicialização do IIS Express já que houveram mudanças no Global.asax após a primeira execução.